# How to change range of xaxis in Plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I need to change the x-axis of this chart. The dataframe has time data per day, from 2012 to October 2022. I want to be able to see in the xaxis all the years and the chart shows me only every 2 years.

```html
import plotly.express as px



fig = px.line(data_SPY, y=['Close'], line_shape='linear', color_discrete_sequence=["#930435"],
              labels={'value': "Precio", 'Date': "Fecha"})
fig.update_layout(
    showlegend=False,
    title= 'Precio SPY ETF',
    font_color= "#000000",
    font_family="Tahoma",
    xaxis = dict(
        tickangle = 0,
        ticklabelstep=1,
        showgrid=True,   
    ), 
    yaxis = dict(
        showgrid=True
    ), 
   legend = dict(
     orientation='v'
   ), 
    paper_bgcolor='#FFFFFF'
)
fig.show(renderer="iframe")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gok3q.png)

Comment: Please add some data to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to specify the dtick.

```
fig.update_xaxes(dtick='Y1')
```